# Prestashop force customer to select country

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7.1.1 and I need to force my shop customers to select country. Now it is always pre selected as my store default country (in my case Lithuania). Option to enable "Set default country from browser language" via International > Localization is not acceptable because a lot of customers is using browser language English, but real country is not United States or United Kingdom. For me it will be the best to set --please chose-- as pre selected value and force customer to select one from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable this behaviour by enabling first select themes\classic\templates_partials\form-fields.tpl if you use classic theme.

An alternative may be to use jQuery :

```
 $("#id_country option:first").prop('disabled',false);
 $("#id_country").val($("#id_country option:first").val());
```